# Docker: Got "permission denied" error at volume mounting directory

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I wrote a `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  notebook:    
    image: jupyter/datascience-notebook
    
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes: 
      - jupyterlabPermanent:/hahaha
    environment:
      JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB: "yes"
      TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"
    command:
      start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
volumes:
  jupyterlabPermanent:
```

Let me make it clear that what characters are appearing on the stage.

- `\hahaha`: container side directory which is located at the root directory
- `jupyterlabPermanent`: volume which is mounted by `hahaha` the container side directory.
- `dockerjulia_jupyterlabPermanent\_data`: host side directory secured for volume `jupyterlabPermanent` which syncronize the data located in `\hahaha`.Full path to `dockerjulia_jupyterlabPermanent\_data` is `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\dockerjulia_jupyterlabPermanent\_data`.

When I use touch command on bash at `\hahaha` directory, I get `permission denied`

```
# bash command line at \hahaha

(base) jovyan@4bcdaa228d9e:/hahaha$ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied
```

Because of this, every tasks done in the container cannot be stored in the `\hahaha` and  `jupyterlabPermanent` volume, and this means data saving is not working in this environment.

How can I solve this?
I searched a bit for this, and found I need to change the configuration of permission, but I don't understand it.

I am using Docker Desktop for Windows with WSL 2 on Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need root access on the volume to change the permissions. So let's run a plain Ubuntu container and mount the volume

```
docker run -it --rm -v jupyterlabPermanent:/hahaha ubuntu
```

now we can change the group ownership to GID 100 which is the group the jovyan user is a member of and also change the permissions to 775 so group members can write to it

```
chown :100 /hahaha
chmod 775 /hahaha
```

Now you can exit the Ubuntu container and run the jupyter container and you should be able to write to the volume.

Comment: Thank you. I got a new insight from your answer. The main problem was that I didn't know the existence of the concept of "owner" and "permission" of Linux system. But, an hour of research and learning let me figure out what the problem here is.

Comment: I tried another solution but I would also like to try the way using chown and chmod as you said here for better understanding of permission system of Linux.

Comment: It's very useful to understand how it works. A thing that's useful in this instance is to know the UID and GID of the user in the Jupyter image. You can see them in some of the first layers in the image here: https://hub.docker.com/layers/jupyter/datascience-notebook/latest/images/sha256-69f9bcbed7cc2b1143e744ea028cd48cda93f1fd93bf96d0a9e1a5b3bf3cf71b?context=explore It varies from image to image what ids are used, so it's nice to know where you can find the info

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for answering my question. The main problem was that I didn't know the existence of the concept of "owner" and "permission" of Linux system. But, an hour of research and learning let me figure out what the problem here is.

## My solution 1

My first solution is to try the following command line on Host console:

```
docker exec -it -u 0 CONATAINER_NAME /bin/bash
```

Adding `-u` option and designating `0`, the User ID of root, lets you dive into the container as you are `root`.

As I checked using `ll` command at the top directory of the container, the permissions of the files and folders at the top directory of the container appears to be dominated by `root`, and the `hahaha` is the one of them.(It means `docker-compose.yml` created `hahaha` directory for volume at the top directory)

```
(base) jovyan@4bcdaa228d9e:/$ ll
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan 26 00:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan 26 00:19 ../
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jan  6 01:47 bin -> usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr 15  2020 boot/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Jan 26 00:19 dev/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Jan 26 00:19 .dockerenv*
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan 26 00:19 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 27 22:18 hahaha/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan 24 20:30 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jan  6 01:47 lib -> usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Jan  6 01:47 lib32 -> usr/lib32/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Jan  6 01:47 lib64 -> usr/lib64/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   10 Jan  6 01:47 libx32 -> usr/libx32/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan  6 01:47 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan  6 01:47 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan 25 02:49 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 217 root root    0 Jan 26 00:19 proc/
drwx------   2 root root 4096 Jan  6 01:50 root/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4096 Jan  6 01:50 run/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Jan  6 01:47 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan  6 01:47 srv/
dr-xr-xr-x  11 root root    0 Jan 26 00:19 sys/
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root 4096 Jan  6 01:50 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan  6 01:47 usr/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jan  6 01:50 var/
```

Therefore, there was no permission for `jovyan` to touch something at `hahaha` at the top directory dominated only by `root`, and this is made it by diving into the container as `root`.

## My solution 2

The second solution is to rewrite the `docker-compose.yml` as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
  notebook:    
    image: jupyter/datascience-notebook
    
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes: 
      # 
      - jupyterlabPermanent:/home/jovyan/hahaha # before ->  jupyterlabPermanent:/hahaha
    environment:
      JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB: "yes"
      TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"
    command:
      start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
volumes:
  jupyterlabPermanent:
```

This change lets docker-compose create container as volume mounting directory is set at `/home/jovyan/hahaha`.
The files and folders under `/home/jovyan` is owned and by `jovyan`(not by `root`) so jovyan can touch some files at `/home/jovyan/hahaha` freely. (No need to dive into the container as `root`)

Comment: this solution didnt work for me, folder created under home/<user>/ is owned by root and container user cannot write there